# Is it possible to install software on Docker Machine?

Tags: windows, docker

I've installed **Docker-Machine** in my **Windows 10** computer.

I'd like to edit the dockerfiles using emacs, but `docker-machine` ships only with vi.

Is there a package manager which I could use to install emacs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker-machine use boot2docker, you can install nano as described here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28733940/how-to-install-nano-on-boot2docker